# Elasticsearch wildcard search: when I add space to a query everything falls apart

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

I have a English dictionary Index, I search fields with the following JSON

```
GET /words/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "default_field": "text",
                  "query": "*orhan*"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "track_total_hits": true
}
```

My query purpose is to get all records if they include `orhan` name, and after running the query I get the results as expected;

| _id | _idex | _score | _type | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B6F1eoQBu3ncIuw4CyKL | words | 0.0 | _doc | ***orhan*** |
| cKN5eoQBu3ncIuw4JgxK | words | 0.0 | _doc | v***orhan***d |
| drDzzYQBu3ncIuw4vn10 | words | 0.0 | _doc | ***orhan*** second word |

I modify my query and I try the search `orhan s` but everything falls apart, the whole 54665 records were shown to me.

```
###
"bool": {
   "should": [
     {
         "query_string": {
         "default_field": "text",
         "query": "*orhan s*" // <- modified
      }
###
```

I can't add the whole response :) But I can provide,
Response of total value:

```
"total": {
  "value": 54665,
  "relation": "eq"
},
```

My response shouldn't include the whole record just related records shown to me

Query: *`"query": "*orhan s*"`*

Response:

| _id | _idex | _score | _type | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| drDzzYQBu3ncIuw4vn10 | words | 0.0 | _doc | ***orhan s***econd word |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the default operator is an OR, so you are catching all the words finishing with orhan **OR** starting with s.

You can change the operator:

```
GET /words/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "default_field": "text",
                  "query": "*orhan s*",
                  "default_operator": "AND"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "track_total_hits": true
}
```

Or add the operator to the query directly:

```
GET /test_words/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "default_field": "text",
                  "query": "*orhan AND s*"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "track_total_hits": true
}
```

Comment: my field type is `keyword` but not working for that field. How can I fix it? Could you please help?